# Multiple check box options

Tags: checkbox, ms-word

I am looking to have check boxes in a Word document that when clicked multiple times, the contents of the box will change from a check, to X, to star or other characters as I need. I have googled around and only can find how to change the check box from an X to a check, but nothing about multiple values.

Thanks,
Larry.